# Retrieving large amount of data using sqlsrv_query

Tags: php, sql, sqlsrv

I am using`sqlsrv_query()` to fetch data from a table having 23 cols and above 15914985 rows

```
select COUNT("id_col") as row_count from tablename;
```

It takes 1 min 40 secs when executing in sql server management studio,

And gives the following error when execute through php:

> 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you
>   are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: Why do you need all the results in one query? It would be better to introduce kind of pagination to the result to retrieve chunks and work with desired fragments.

Comment: i am searching for options but i do not found option to select data between a range like limit in mysql

Comment: i need the total count of rows to do pagination calculations and display purpose but it gives error.

Comment: @VipinSoni Did you tried increasing `max_execution_time` in `php.ini`?